# Oracle APEX - display only field is bold

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

Not sure why this is happening but I have a `display only` field on my form and both the label and the field value come up as bold. Is there an easy way to un-bold the value part without applying CSS?

Comment: Maybe not.  Are you using Universal Theme?  What label template are you using?

Comment: yes, I am using Universal theme. The template used is `Required - Above` with default template options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a template option that takes care of this.  I believe you will need to use some kind of CSS to do this.  At the item level that could be:

```
style="font-weight: normal"
```

Or for **all** display items on the page you could add this CSS fragment in Inline CSS for the page:

```
.apex-item-display-only {font-weight: normal}
```